# Error while running vagrant

Tags: linux, vagrant, opensuse

I am receiving the following error while running vagrant. I have searched many posts but no luck. I have tried it with vagrant 1.2.7, 1.2.6 and 1.2.3 versions but receiving same error.

OS: opensuse 12.3 x86_64
vagrant 1.2.3

```
Bringing machine 'vb' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[vb] Importing base box 'precise64'...
[vb] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[vb] Setting the name of the VM...
[vb] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[vb] Creating shared folders metadata...
[vb] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[vb] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) wlan0
2) eth0
What interface should the network bridge to? 1
[vb] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[vb] Forwarding ports...
[vb] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[vb] -- 8080 => 8080 (adapter 1)
[vb] Booting VM...
[vb] Destroying VM and associated drives...
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:24:in `block in interpolate_hash': missing interpolation argument in "There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant\nfor controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.\n\nCommand: %{command}\n\nStderr: %{stderr}" ({:_key=>:vboxmanage_error, :_namespace=>"vagrant.errors", :command=>"[\"startvm\", \"f25fb286-b323-4d06-9474-0510d946a228\", \"--type\", \"headless\"]"} given) (I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:19:in `gsub'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:19:in `interpolate_hash'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb:15:in `interpolate'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:144:in `interpolate'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:41:in `translate'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:156:in `block in translate'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `translate'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/errors.rb:82:in `translate_error'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/errors.rb:58:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_4_2.rb:458:in `exception'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_4_2.rb:458:in `raise'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_4_2.rb:458:in `start'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/boot.rb:16:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:31:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/sane_defaults.rb:49:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/set_hostname.rb:16:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/forward_ports.rb:31:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:105:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/share_folders.rb:25:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_shared_folders.rb:12:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:11:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/nfs.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prune_nfs_exports.rb:15:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:118:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:45:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:35:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in `action'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vagrant-1.2.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: Can you try to start the VM directly from the VirtualBox manager? It should give you a more explicit error message.

Comment: Looks like the VM got destroyed when booting up. Make sure you are using the latest VirtualBox 4.2.16, also try to enable debug `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` to start the VM see more debug output. BTW: paste your `Vagrantfile` here.